# How do I style this text?

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, line-breaks

I'm new in asp.net and C#,
so here goes the question:

This is my content.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeFile="content.aspx.cs" Inherits="Indhold" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="Server">
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$    ConnectionStrings:mydb %>"></asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"   AutoGenerateColumns="false" Font-Size="12pt">
<Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Mest læst artikler">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("titel") %>'></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("visitAntal") %>'>      </asp:Label>
            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,    "indhold").ToString().Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />").Replace("\n", "<br />") %>
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx">Tilbage til   forside</asp:HyperLink>
</asp:Content>
```

My content.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;

public partial class Indhold : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.QueryString["str"] != null)
        {
            String str = Request.QueryString["str"];

            SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM Artikler WHERE titel ='" + str + "'";
            GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Text = str;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

Well I can't post images,
so this is now it looks like:

test1  (titel)

7  (visitAntal)

dsadasdjks dasda dsadsa dasdsads dsadas dsadas dasdasd dsdsa sd  (indhold)

Someone please help me with this; how can I style it so it will looks like this:

test1  (titel)

7  (visitAntal)

**dsadasdjks**

dasda dsadsa dasdsads

**dsadas**

*dsadas*

dasdasd dsdsa sd  (indhold)

Please I need help for this, I've been searching for solutions for this problem, but I just don't know what to search or maybe I just don't understand what I've seen.
So please if some one can explain this.

Comment: Upload your image to [Imgur](http://imgur.com) and paste a link here - someone will edit it in for you

Answer (score 0):

```
<p>
test1 (titel)
<br>
7 (visitAntal)
<br>
<b>dsadasdjks</b>
<br>
dasda dsadsa dasdsads
<br>
<b>dsadas</b>
<br>
dsadas
<br>
dasdasd dsdsa sd (indhold)
</p>
```

Seems like you want a line break, nested the html tag properly based on your condition.